# Как исправить проблему в VScode файл Setting

Tags: visual-studio-code

Set the save location of exported CSS.

Set the relative path from Workspace Root.

'/' stands for your workspace root.

Example: /subfolder1/subfolder2. (NOTE: if folder does not exist, folder will be created as well).

Must start with any of:
`/` or `\` (for workspace root)
`~/` or `~\` for relative to the file being processed. Must not end with a path separator (`/` or `\`)

И еще вот такая проблема, подчеркнуто значение null и пишет:
Incorrect type. Expected "string".

Купил ноут поставил Vscode сделал синхронизацию восстановил все свои настройки и тут такая ерунда. Делал установку от имени Админа. Переустанавливал пару раз все бестолку. Как фиксить чтобы все было норм я не знаю. Кто с таким сталкивался дайте ответ пж.

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUgtn.png[![введите](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUgtn.png%5B!%5B%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5) сюда описание изображения][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUgtn.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUgtn.png)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сменить Live Sass Compiler на другого автора. Там два одинаковых названия